# How to download PDF file from blob oracle using PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

I want to download blob file from oracle, that is PDF file, this is my code to get and download file:

```
<?php
$conn = ocilogon('user', 'pass', '//localhost/XE');
$sql = "SELECT PDFFILE FROM TFILE";
    $stid = ociparse($conn,$sql);
    ociexecute($stid);
    $rowResult = ocifetch($stid);
    settype($arrayResult,"array");
if($rowResult != null){
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . OCIResult($stid,'PDFFILE') . '"');    
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize(OCIResult($stid,'PDFFILE')->load()));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    }
    ?>
```

but when i run this code,i not get pdf file..
 something wrong with my code??

Comment: If you didn't get the PDF file, what _did_ you get?  Was there an error?  What was in the response from the server?

Comment: The download window is appear but the file that is downloaded not The file that's not i want. The downloaded file is .php extention.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . OCIResult($stid,'PDFFILE') . '"');    
header("Content-Length: " . filesize(OCIResult($stid,'PDFFILE')->load()));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
```

You're sending the `Content-Disposition` header twice.  You probably don't even need the second one, the client should know all it needs to know about the stream from the `Content-Type` header.  Omit the second `Content-Disposition` so you're not over-writing the header that has the filename.

Comment: i had removed 'header('Content-Disposition: attachment; header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n")', but i still not get the pdf file. exactly i get the php page (text.php)

Comment: When you say you "get the PHP page" what exactly do you mean?  Do you get a PDF file _called_ `text.php`?  Do you get the _actual_ PHP file with the PHP code visible?

Comment: text.php is containt code to show page where i try to download pdf before.

Comment: If you're seeing the *actual PHP code* on the client then the problem has nothing to do with the code itself.  Your PHP server isn't processing the PHP code.  It's a server configuration problem.  You should _never_ see the PHP code on the client-side.

Comment: How can I set the Server Configuration?

Comment: @MuhammadHandaLithani: That's both out of scope for this question and for this site.  You may be able to ask useful questions about that at ServerFault, it's more on-topic there.  But I doubt they're going to just give you a tutorial on it, Stack Exchange doesn't really provide tutorials.  There are plenty of tutorials online, though.  You might also want to buy a book on PHP that includes installation and configuration.